# find referring page in asp.net mvc after a jquery redirect

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, redirect, referrer

I am faking an autopostback using jquery since I am using asp.net mvc. It's being performed in a select list (dropdownlist) like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // autopostback for character drop down list
    $('#playerCharacters').change(function() {
        var charId = $('#playerCharacters option:selected').val();
        window.location = "/Character/SetDefault/" + charId;
    });
});
```

Now in /Character/SetDefault/[charID] (controller, action, ID) I am trying to access the referring URL using this:

```
Request.UrlReferrer
```

But it's coming up null. Any ideas on why that is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think setting the window.location directly is treated by the browser the same as it would treat the user directly entering a new URL into the location bar. This means that there's no referrer since referrers are about one page directly referring to another, (eg. via a link) not the browser just going to another page...

Easiest way I can see to solve your issue is to make sure your drop down list is in a form that posts (or gets) to /Character/SetDefault & then make your javascript submit the form like this:

```
$('#playerCharacters').change(function() {
    this.form.submit();
});
```

You'll then just need to change your SetDefault action in your controller to have a playerCharacters parameter so that the MVC will bind the form's request value to your method properly.